# Powershell script to pull remote pc serial number then match against an xlsx file then match against another and output only needed info

Tags: excel, powershell

hey im trying to build a powershell script that will pull a serial number from a remote pc and then match that against an xlsx file which would then match a column against another xlsx file i have gotten to the point where i can pull the remote sn and have everything put in to a csv output but i am having issues matching the data then filtering based on the match and then outputting only what i need im new to scripting so im pretty sure its more my lack of experiance than anything else this is my code so far

```
    $computers = Get-Content c:\script\computerlist.txt
    Get-wmiobject Win32_Bios -ComputerName $computers | Select-Object __SERVER, SerialNumber| Format-Table |out-file C:\script\computerinfo.txt

    $computerinfo = Import-Excel C:\script\compDB.xlsx
    $userinfo = Import-Excel C:\script\userDB.xlsx

    $Computerinfo[2].SERIAL -eq
    $Computerinfo[2].DATE_ADDED
    $Computerinfo[2].OS
    $Computerinfo[2].MODEL
    $Computerinfo[2].USER
    $userinfo[2].NAME_FIRST
    $userinfo[2].NAME_LAST
    $userinfo[2].NT_USERID

    ''
    'Computer Info' 
    '----------'

     $computerinfo ,$userinfo | Format-Table - | Out-File c:\script\computerinfo.csv
```

Comment: whats the question here?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to save the wmi information to a variable:

```
$WMIinfo = Get-wmiobject Win32_Bios -ComputerName $computers | Select-Object __SERVER, SerialNumber
```

Then you would need to loop through the spreadsheet and compare to data in Computer spreadsheet. If it matches loop through user spreadsheet for match:

```
foreach ($CompEntry in $Computerinfo) {
    if ($WMIinfo.serial -eq $CompEntry.serial) {
       foreach ($UserEntry in $userinfo) {
           if ($UserEntry.NT_USERID -eq $CompEntry.USER) {
                #output information you want here
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: so i have made my script work partially using BenH's info and im alot closer to what im looking for i now get all the information i need but i have to manully change a variable to have it match the xlsx file it doesnt search through it

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to help you get there.

I created an Excel file called Serial.xslx.  Here's what it looks like

```
SerialNumber    DeployedTo
212             Ham
4M24N32         Stephen
```

I then import this as `$list`.

```
$list = import-excel C:\temp\serial.xlsx
```

Next,to get the Win32_Bios info, so I can grab the SerialNumber property.

```
$bios = get-WmiObject Win32_Bios
```

Finally, I'll filter through the `$list` (which contains the Excel file), and find a row which has a SerialNumber that matches this computers serial number.  If I find a matching one, then I grab the .DeployedTo value for that record.

```
$user = $list | Where SerialNumber -eq $bios.SerialNumber | Select -ExpandProperty DeployedTo
```

All that remains is to demonstrate that it works.

```
"the computer with serial $($bios.SerialNumber) is deployed to $user"

>the computer with serial 4M24N32 is deployed to Stephen
```

Now, you've got two separate excel files, so I would either manually join them into one, or repeat this same basic approach.

Comment: `import-excel` isnt a native cmdlet of PowerShell is it? Ah the  op has it already. nvm